# How to Sync Gradle with Apache Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I installed Apache Cordova on my pc and everything is fine but...

when i try to build every project... (in Command Line Interface) cordova is trying to download Gradle...

> Command Prompt Output :
>
> ---
>
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk
>
> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92
>
> Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

but i already installed gradle and added it to system path variables...

`Note : I can import project into android studio and build it..`

I just need to sync mine Gradle to ApacheCordova and build it

Thanks

Comment: Have posted an answer for this question in the following link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349019/error-when-building-a-cordova-android-project/ Please check it out and let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks, After this Cordova is downloading lots of JAR file (10m) so prject `built successfully`, I just want to do this solution with Cordova core to every time I dont need to do this and download again...

Comment: Need to check on this. Atleast this solution will avoid gradle download. Should i post this answer?

Comment: Yepe! , It's solution i just searching for JAR problems... So...

Comment: You can accept the answer if it was helpful so that i can be useful to others too

Comment: Was the solution helpful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid gradle download for each build, you may follow the workaround as follows:

1) Download the required gradle version zip file from gradle distribution link and save it in local folder.

2) Navigate to `PROJECT_ROOT_FOLDER/platforms/android/cordova/lib/builders` folder and edit `GradleBuilder.js` file

3) Change the line from: `var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';`

to

`'var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'file:///local/path/to/folder/where/gradle/zip/is/saved/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';` 
and save the file

4) Try rebuilding android build.

You can also try the following as quick fix,

1) In command prompt execute the following command: `export CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL=file:///local/path/to/folder/where/gradle/zip/is/saved/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip`

2) Execute the following command: `cordova run android`