# Cordova/PhoneGap - Build failed Error code 1 for command

Tags: android, ios, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, phonegap-build

I am doing a cordova app.
The iOS is running well. But today, I tried it for Android.
When I run the command : cordova build android I have the build failed :

```
* Where:
Build file '/Users/guillaume/Desktop/fcm/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'android']
   > Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/guillaume/Desktop/fcm/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED


Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/guillaume/Desktop/fcm/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/guillaume/Desktop/fcm/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

I tried to do what it says : change `fcm/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip` 
The fact is, in my cordova folder (named fcm), I  don't have gradle folder.

UPDATE:
I have to tell you that I changed the package name in config.xml.
Before that, the build was ok in Android, but I couldn't run the APK because it was signed with a package already used.

What am I supposed to do ?

Comment: check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37367247/how-to-sync-gradle-with-apache-cordova

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove platform android and re add it before build. I may work for some of you.